# Setting up the correct work of the backgroundworker

Tags: c#

I have a problem with setting up the proper display of the brackground worker in the progress bar.

Namely, I want to be loaded into the datagrid, while the ecel is loading into my progressive bar. This is my current code, it works, but first I get excel and then the backgroundworker, how can I set it to be done in parallel?

```
      private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int process = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).Process;
        int delay = ((DataParameter)e.Argument).Delay;
        int index = 1;

        try
        {
            //for (int i = 0; i < process; i++)
            //{
                //if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
                //{
                //    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(index++ * 100 / process, string.Format("Process data {0}", i));
                //    Thread.Sleep(delay);
                //}
            // }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        lblPercent.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
        progress.Update();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Process has been completed.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    private void buttonBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "File Excel|*.xlsx";
        DialogResult re = fd.ShowDialog();
        excel_name = fd.SafeFileName;
        if (re == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileName = fd.FileName;

            if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                inputParameter.Delay = 100;
                inputParameter.Process = 200;
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(inputParameter);
                ReadExcel(fileName); 
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadExcel(string Path)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        int rCnt;
        int cCnt;
        int rw = 0;
        int cl = 0;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        rw = range.Rows.Count;
        cl = range.Columns.Count;
        int tenPercent = rw / 10;
        int percentCounter = 0;
        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
        {
            for (cCnt = 0; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
            {
                no = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value);
                name = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 2] as Excel.Range).Value);
                time_to = Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, 3] as Excel.Range).Value);
            }
            if (++percentCounter == tenPercent)
            {
                double progress = rCnt / (double)rw;
                lblPercent.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}%", 100 * progress);
                percentCounter = 0;
            }
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(no);
            string date =  dt.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");

            double d = double.Parse(name);
            DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
            string time = conv.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            double f = double.Parse(time_to);
            DateTime conv2 = DateTime.FromOADate(f);
            string time2 = conv2.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

            epg_id = ((range.Cells[rCnt, 4] as Excel.Range).Value);


            SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
            sqliteCon.Open();
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM EPGdaten WHERE File=@File";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, sqliteCon);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@File", epg_id));
            sqdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqdr.Read())
            {
               string s = sqdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
               string b = sqdr.GetValue(3).ToString();
               dataGridView1.Rows.Add(date, time, time2, s, b);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(date, time, time2);
            }


            sqdr.Close();
            sqliteCon.Close();
            sqliteCon.Dispose();
        }
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
```

I'm the beginner, I've watched a lot of examples, for the first time I've been doing this and I have not managed to get in ..

thank you all for help

Comment: Shouldn't the call to ReadExcel() be moved within the backgroundWorker_DoWork() method? I think your current version fully reads the excel before the background worker is started. That background worker currently isn't doing any real work is it?

Comment: Start the background worker before you read excel.  The backgroundworker is running asynchronously and will run while you are reading the excel file.

Comment: Yes.  ReadExcel is a synchronous method and the backgroundworker will not start until ReadExcel is finished.  Move ReadExcel() after the backgroundworker is started.

Comment: @jdweng Can you base my code to show me where should I put it? I do what I do wrong by showing me. thanks a lot

Comment: In the method  buttonLoadExcel_Click() move ReadExcel() to last line.

Comment: What was the results?  May be the ReadExcel is executing faster than you expect.

Comment: The percentage is rCnt/rw from the ReadExcel() method and not the code you are using in the DoWork() method.

Comment: should be index++ * process / 100 rather than  100 / process

Comment: You do not need the for loop in DoWork.  Just call ReadExcel().

Comment: You need to call backgroundWorker.ReportProgress() at every 10% and then at end so you get 100%.

Comment: Instead of the console write you should be reporting progress.

Comment: Can't tell.  You need to do some debugging and find out exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put code like this in your ReadExcel method

```
            int rw = 967;
            int tenPercent = rw / 10;
            int percentCounter = 0;
            for (int rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
            {

                if( ++percentCounter == tenPercent )
                {
                    double progress = rCnt / (double)rw;
                    Console.WriteLine("Progress : {0}%", 100 * progress);
                    percentCounter = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: At end of for loop you should do one additional update to progress and set to 100%.  The fractions are rarely going to be exactly at 10% steps.